# Why does the Pycharm debugger and the python running program give two different results after append?

Tags: python, debugging, numpy, append, pycharm

I don't understand. For identical situations can the debugging console and running program return different results? How?

```
    arrRegion_masks = []
    test = []
    for image_stack in videoData:
        for i in xrange(numROIs):
            roi = self.vb.rois[i]
            arrRegion_mask   = roi.getROIMask(image_stack,self.vb.img, axes=(0,1)) ## BREAKPOINT HERE
            arrRegion_masks = arrRegion_masks.append(arrRegion_mask)
```

I have a breakpoint at the call to retrieve the mask. `ArrRegion_mask` is returned and is simply a 2D numpy array that looks as follows:

```
>>> arrRegion_mask
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Then if I step past the next line to append this to `arrRegion_masks` it becomes `None` which then leads to

```
  File "/home/cornelis/PycharmProjects/BMDanalyse/BMDanalyse/BMDanalyse.py", line 343, in getBMD
    arrRegion_masks = arrRegion_masks.append(arrRegion_mask)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I also get this when not in debugging mode.

Why is this especially confusing? Because while I am at the breakpoint and in my debugger I can bring up the python prompt and do the following and get exactly what I'd expect

```
>>> test = test.append(arrRegion_mask)
>>> test
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]])]
```

So the debugger and my running code give **different** results for *identical situations*? This is extremely disturbing to me as it means I must not be understanding something quite fundamental as I had always thought this shouldn't. Please help explain it to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`append`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm) is an inplace action (and returns `None`).  You don't need to do reassignment.  The first time you do

```
arrRegion_masks = arrRegion_masks.append(arrRegion_mask)
```

`arrRegion_masks` gets the new value appended, but then `append` returns `None` and you assign it to `arrRegion_masks`.  So now `arrRegion_masks` is `None` and the next time through the loop you try to use `append` again (causing your error)

Just do

```
arrRegion_masks.append(arrRegion_mask)
```